# changing anchor tag into button with javascript/jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, forms, html, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to change my anchor tag to a button and have it function properly but it seems when I change this:

```
var editButton = document.createElement('a');


        editButton.href = "#additem";
```

this:

```
var editButton = document.createElement('button');


        editButton.href = "#additem";
```

The button when clicked, doesn't do anything. If I switch it back however, the link works fine... my goal is essentially to change the anchor text into an actual jquery button.

I've also tried setting the attribute class to ui button but that did nothing as well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button does not have a property of href, what you can do is lsten to the onclick event of the button like this:

```
var editButton = document.createElement('button'); 
editButton.onclick = function(e){ location.href = 'http://' + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname +'#additem'}
```

Comment: Great worked perfect, I tried doing the same for my delete button, but since my delete button is actually using something like this to call a function already:

var deleteButton = document.createElement('a');
deleteButton.addEventListener("click", deleteItem);
deleteButton.href = "#";

How would I go about doing it to that? I've tried this:

  var deleteButton = document.createElement('button'); 
  deleteButton.onclick = function(e){ deleteItem(); }

But it seems to run the function twice , and ask the user if they want to delete the record twice?

Comment: well you can always join 2 function in one function like this: onclick= function(){func1(); funct2()}

Comment: I'm trying to make it call the deleteItem function once,but it's happening twice with the way I have it. I'm not trying to call two functions, just that one.

Comment: Nevermind, apparently I could just setAttribute to data-role button and it works fine :P